# Back functionality of browser is not working

Tags: reactjs

I have written the following code with a Query string corresponding to the filters applied. On clicking browser's back button I want to get back to the previous set of filters, but instead I land back to the browser's home page every time.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react'
import {DropDownList, MultiSelect} from "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns"
import {Button} from '@progress/kendo-react-buttons'
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

const Filter = () => {
    
    const history=useHistory()
    const location=useLocation()
    const [Standard,setStandard] = useState("All")
    const [Hobbies,setHobbies] = useState(["Playing"])
    const [Responsibility,setResponsibility] = useState("All")
    const [QueryString,setQueryString] = useState(location.search.substring(1))

    const options={
        StandardList:["All","VI","VII","VIII"],
        HobbiesList: ["Playing", "Drawing","Swimming"],
        ResponsibilityList:["All","Monitor","Head","Sports Captain"]
    }

    const handleApply = ()=>{  
        setQueryString(`Standard=${JSON.stringify(Standard)}&Responsibility=${JSON.stringify(Responsibility)}&IncidentStatus=${JSON.stringify(Hobbies)}`)
    }

    const backButtonEvent = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        history.goBack()
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('popstate',backButtonEvent);
        return ()=>{
            window.removeEventListener('popstate',backButtonEvent);
        }
    },[backButtonEvent])

    useEffect(() => {
        var params= new URLSearchParams((QueryString)?(QueryString):`Standard=${JSON.stringify(Standard)}&Responsibility=${JSON.stringify(Responsibility)}&IncidentStatus=${JSON.stringify(Hobbies)}`)
        history.push({search: params.toString()})
    }, [QueryString])

    return (
        <div>
            <label>Standard </label>
            <DropDownList data={options.StandardList} defaultValue={"All"} value={Standard} 
            onChange={(event)=>setStandard(event.target.value)}/> 

            <label > Hobbies </label>
            <MultiSelect data={options.HobbiesList} defaultValue={["Playing"]} value={Hobbies} onChange={(event)=>setHobbies([...event.value])}/>
        
            <label > Responsibility </label>
            <DropDownList data= {options.ResponsibilityList} defaultValue= {"All"} value={Responsibility} onChange={(event)=>setResponsibility(event.target.value)} />

            <Button id="submitFilter" type="button" onClick={handleApply} > Apply </Button>   
        </div>
    )  
}

export default Filter
```

Why am I getting this behaviour and how can I resolve it?

Comment: what is `history.push({search: params.toString()})`, should we push in the entire address without using `search` ?

Comment: History Object contains following:

location:
hash: ""
key: "b5nx64"                                                                                                                                search: ""
pathname: "/".
Since the path is same and only the search parameter is getting changed because of change in filters, that's why I am modifying the history whenever query string changes just by pushing in the search parameter.